# Delete specific object from array - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Node.js.
I have some data like this

[image]

I want to update this song object and remove artist "hanna" .. so ultimately song will be left with no artist.

I have tried many ways, some of them are commented here

here is my code:

```
var data = req.body;

  let songCondition = {
    "artist.$.id": data._id,
  }
  let updateSong = {
    // $pull: { "artist": { "id": data._id } }
    // $pull: { "artist": { "id": { $in: [data._id] } } }
    $pull: { artist: { $elemMatch: { id: data._id } } }
  }

  let updateSongData = await Query.findAndUpdate(Song, songCondition, updateSong);
```

Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [**`findOneAndUpdate`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) function first argument is for `filter` and second one is for `update`

```
const { _id } = req.body

Song.findAndUpdate(
  { "songs.artist": { "$elemMatch": { id: _id }}}, // first parameter is for fitler
  { "$pull": { "artist": { "id": _id } } } // second one for update
)
```

Comment: thanks man, you saved the day :)